# Passing data between view controllers with a UIAlertAction in Swift

Tags: swift2

I have a tableView, and when the user taps a cell, it opens an alert box with the options "Close" and "Search". The handler for "Search" is shown below as `func searchSongAction`.

This presents a new viewcontroller (embedded in a Nav Bar) that searches the song online. In this new viewcontroller, `Search`, there are 2 functions: one searches the song currently playing and the other searches the song that the user asked to search from the tableView alert.

I am trying to pass the data from the cell into the Search class, but I keep coming up short. I feel like what I have is correct, but that is obviously not he case.

Any ideas?

Ask me if you need any more information.

> History.swift

```
func searchSongAction(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Search") as! Search
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
    let targetController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as! Search
    targetController.searchType = "Previous"
    targetController.songNowText = self.songToSearch
    targetController.artistNowText = self.artistToSearch
}
```

> Search.swift

```
class Search: UIViewController {

var songNowText = ""
var artistNowText = ""
var searchType = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if searchType == "Previous" {
        searchSongPrevious()
    } else {
        searchSongNow()
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually performing a Segue from your `searchSongAction:` function, so I'm guessing that `prepareForSegue:sender:` isn't actually being called and therefore the setup is not running.

Try assigning `searchType`, `songNowText` and `artistNowText` on `vc` inside of `searchSongAction:`:

```
func searchSongAction(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Search") as! Search

    //Setup the properties
    vc.searchType = "Previous"
    vc.songNowText = self.songToSearch
    vc.artistNowText = self.artistToSearch

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As a side note, typically you'll want to call `super`'s implementation of a function when overriding it (you have neglected to do this in `prepareForSegue:sender:`)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I didn't consider that I wasn't calling the prepareForSegue. Thanks a lot.